# How to change security settings in Wine IE?

Tags: ubuntu, internet-explorer, wine

I have to access office PC using https://portal.mycompany.net/Remote
It require ActiveX. I am using ubuntu 12.04
The only option I found I could use it to install wine and ies4linux ( VM won't work for me since my PC has not enough resources )
I was able to set it up and start IE but it gave me the message:
"Your current security settings prohibit running ActiveX controls on this page. As a result, the page may not display correctly."
After I click "OK" button I've got another messge:
"This portion of the Remote Web Workplace requires the Microsoft Remote Desktop ActiveX Control. You browser's security settings may be preventing you from downloading ActiveX controls. Adjust these settings, and try to connect again".

My question:
How could I change security seetings in Wine IE? I don't this this option like in MS IE.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I decided to give  up this approach and instead used PlayOnLinux which was much easier for me.
Thread could be closed